# Gnuplot read line style from data file column

Tags: gnuplot

I'd like to draw an impulse graph from a text file that looks like this:

```
II 5 0 0 288.40 1.3033e+14 
II 6 0 0 289.60 1.5621e+14 
II 1 4 0 302.70 3.0084e+13 
II 2 4 0 303.40 4.0230e+13 
II 1 5 1 304.40 3.4089e+13
```

The plot conceptually should be `plot "datafile.dat" using 5:6 w impulses ls $2`.

Basically, given a previously defined set of line styles, I'd like to input the line style number from column 2 for every couple of plotted points from column 5 and 6.
Also I'd like to create a text box, for every plotted point, taking strings from the first four columns.

Does somebody know if that's possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the data from column two as line style use `set style increment user` and `linecolor variable`:

```
set style increment user
plot "datafile.dat" using 5:6:2 with impulses lc var
```

In order to place a label, use the `labels` plotting style:

```
plot "datafile.dat" using 5:6:1 with labels offset 0,1
```

Putting everything together, you have:

```
set style increment user
set for [i=1:6] style line i lt i
set yrange [0:*]
set offsets 0,0,graph 0.1,0
plot "datafile.dat" using 5:6:2 with impulses lc var, "" using 5:6:1 with labels offset 0,1
```

The result with 4.6.3 is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the helpful answer above. It almost solved my problem

I'm actually trying to use a column from my data file to specify a linestyle (dot, squares,triangles, whatever as long as it's user-defined), and not a linecolor. Is there any way to do that?

This line works : I get points with different colors (specified in column 4), but the point style is the same.

```
plot "$file" u 1:2:4 w p notitle lc var, "" using 1:2:3 with labels offset 0,1 notitle
```

Replacing `lc` with `ls` after defining my own styles doesn't work (`ls` can't have `variable` as an option)
I can live without different linestyles, but it would be much prettier.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to replace the line`set for [i=1:6] style line i lt i` for `set for [i=1:6] style line i lt i pt %`, Where `%` can be any type of point you want